# Why is model not loading and throws an System.NUllReferenceException when loading paritial view

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view, model

From source App_Web_td5sjcre, the NullReferenceException, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." occurs. This happens when I load the home page with a partial view that contains a List.

@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")

```
@model IEnumerable<ApplicationName.Models.Stuff>

</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Am trying to load this within the Home Page in a div as a partial view.

This is what am using to call the partial view in the home page:

`@Html.Partial("~\Views\Home\View.cshtml")`

The parent view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}



<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
       Some stuff here.    
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        Display list here:
        <div id="myPartialview">

            @*@Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/View.cshtml")*@
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you calling this in home page view ?

Comment: What is the type of the model of the parent view?

Comment: Am calling it using. `@Html.partial("~View/Home/View.cshtml")`

Comment: I am sorry, added the parent view to the question.

Comment: Sorry, typo, should be:
`@Html.partial("~/View/Home/View.cshtml")`, forget a /.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your partial view is expecting a collection of `Stuff` object to be passed to that. I am assuming that your are not passing a non null value (a valid List of Stuff) when calling this partial.

So instead of doing this

```
@Html.partial("~View/Home/View.cshtml")
```

You should be doing.

```
@Html.partial("~View/Home/View.cshtml",SomeVariableOfTypeStuffList)
```

So if your parent model is strongly typed to a view model which has a property of type List, you may pass that property to this partial.

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
   public List<ApplicationName.Models.Stuff> Stuffs { set;get;}
   public HomeViewModel()
   {
       this.Stuffs= new List<ApplicationName.Models.Stuff>();
   }
}
```

So in your GET action of the parent view(Home), send an object of this

```
public ActionResult Home()
{
  var vm=new HomeViewModel();
  // to do : Load vm.Stuffs
  return View(vm);
}
```

Now in your Home view,

```
@model HomeViewModel
<div class="col-lg-8">
        Display list here:
        <div id="myPartialview">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/View.cshtml",Model.Stuffs)
        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do I need to add an another reference to the model to add that to the partial method? Like @Model?

Comment: Okay, I added something like this,

`<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
       Some stuff here.    
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        Display list here:
        <div id="myPartialview">
           @model ApplicationName.Models.Stuff
           @Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/View.cshtml")
        </div>

    </div>
</div>`

Though now I get error in partial view at:

`@foreach (var item in Model) {`

Comment: Thanks! That works. What I did was pass the Model in the HomeController with the model into View method. and then seemingly referenced the Model.Stuff in the Partial method.